# Elastic search aggregation with a field which have both keyword and text type

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, aggregate, loopbackjs, aggregation

How to do aggregation in Elastic search with a field which has both keyword and text types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the aggregation on the keyword field. Ie field.keyword

Comment: Thanks, Dadoonet for the advice. 
I tried the same but it won't work for me.

I'm adding the aggregation that I tried.

`{
    "aggs": {
        "chosen": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "choice.response_text"
            }
        }
    }
}`

here where can I add the `.keyword` 

Can you please help me for the same

Comment: choice.response_text.keyword

Comment: Sorry Dadoonet, It doesn't work for me. Instead of that I have changed its filed type and migrated the data.

Thanks for your time

Comment: It should work as I wrote OOTB unless you changed the default mapping which you didn't tell.